# Function to accept a matrix as input and goes element by element using for-loops adding one to each of the elements

Tags: matlab

I have created a function to add one to an element as follows;

```
function xz = addOne(x)
nrow = size(x,1);
ncol = size(x,1);

for K = 1:nrow
    for J = 1:ncol
        xz = x(:) + 1; 
    end
end
```

Example: given 1 the function results in 2:

```
addOne(1) [2]
```

I have tried using a matrix as an argument for the function...

```
x = [1 2 3; 0 0 0; 4 5 6];

x =

 1     2     3
 0     0     0
 4     5     6

addOneWithFors(x)

ans =

     2
     1
     5
     3
     1
     6
     4
     1
     7
```

How would I update this function to accept a matrix with multiple rows and columns and output it as such instead of just 1 number or a list of elements. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: To work with the elements of a matrix one by one, you have to Index your input matrix using the indices K and J. Matrix indices are explained here: https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/getting-started-with-matlab.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Matlab, you don't need a special function to do this. Matlab natively supports adding a scalar to a matrix. For example:

```
x = [1 2 3; 0 0 0; 4 5 6];
y = x + 1
```

will produce:

```
y =

     2     3     4
     1     1     1
     5     6     7
```

However, if you specifically want to write this out explicitly using `for` loops, then your `addOne()` function only needs minor modifications. For example:

```
function xz = addOne(x)
nrow = size(x,1);
ncol = size(x,2);

xz = zeros(nrow,ncol);
for K = 1:nrow
    for J = 1:ncol
        xz(K,J) = x(K,J) + 1; 
    end
end
```

Note that `ncol = size(x,2);` has been defined correctly.